# DateFormatter pandas is plotting wrong dates after resampling DF Hourly

Tags: python, dateformatter, pandas-resample

I'm trying to resample my df hourly and plot the data. However, when I resample hourly DateFormatter is plotting wrong dates and also wrong intervals.

If I resample the data daily it works fine. Any idea how to solve this issue. Below you can find the code I'm using.

resample is on line #23. Change from 'D' to 'H' to test the code.
to install the library: pip install seebuoy

Thank you so much.

```
from seebuoy import ndbc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

buoy = 46235

title = 'Imperial Beach Nearshore (21 m)\nStation 46235'#- Maximun Daily' '
begin = '2020-09-01 00:00' # Begin of data set  YYYY/MM/DD
end = '2021-03-31 00:00' # end of data set  YYYY/MM/DD

years = ndbc.available_years(buoy, "stdmet")
df_store = []
for year in years[-3:]:
  df_store.append(ndbc.historic(buoy, year, dataset="stdmet"))

df = pd.concat(df_store)

df = df[(df.index > begin) & (df.index <= end)]

df=df.resample('H').agg(dict(wvht='max', dpd='mean', apd='median', mwd='mean'))

# Ploting dataset
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10,8))
df.wvht.plot(ax=ax[0], color=['black'], linewidth=1)

ax[0].set_yticks([0,1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ax[0].set_ylabel('Wave Hs, m', fontsize=9)
ax[0].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=9)
ax[0].yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

df.apd.plot(ax=ax[1], color=['black'], linewidth=1)
# df2.Ta.plot(ax=ax[1], color=['red'], linewidth=1)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Period, sec',fontsize=9)
ax[1].set_ylim(1,16)
ax[1].set_yticks([0,4,8,12,16])
ax[1].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=9)
ax[1].yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

df.mwd.plot(ax=ax[2], color=['black'], linewidth=1)
ax[2].set_ylabel('Wave Direction',fontsize=9)
ax[2].set_ylim(0,360)
ax[2].set_yticks(([0,90,180,270, 360]))
ax[2].tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=9)
ax[2].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(3))
ax[2].yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))


date_form = DateFormatter('%d%b\n%Y')
ax[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
# ax[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=15))
# ax[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=12))
ax[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
# ax[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))

ax[2].tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=9, rotation=0)
for tick in ax[2].xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
          tick.set_horizontalalignment("center")
```

Comment: I solved the problem replacing `df.WVHT.plot(ax=ax[0], color=['black'], linewidth=1)` by  `ax[0].plot(df.index, df.WVHT, color = 'black', linewidth = 1)` in each of the three plotting codes.

Any better solution?